# How to iterate over objects indexed by a domain in Chapel

Tags: chapel

I have a set of objects var Players: [domain] Player and I'd like to iterate over the objects in reverse order. Something like

This works

```
for p in Players by {
   writeln(p.name);
   writeln("I was the %i st player added".format(p.pid)")  // pid corresponds to domain index.
   p.shoeSize = 1.5*p.shoeSize
}
```

But!

```
// poops
for p in Players by -1 {
   writeln(p.name);
   writeln("I was the %i -to-last player added".format(p.pid)")  // pid corresponds to domain index.
   p.shoeSize = 1.5*p.shoeSize
}
```

And I want to make sure the shoe size updates.

== UPDATE ==

Some additional information / specs to honor @bencray's request

```
class Player {
  var name: string,
      position: string,
      pid: int,
      shoeSize: int;
}

var playerDom = {1..0},
    players: [playerDom] Player;

writeln("I have %i players".format(playerDom.size));
// Now add some players
// Better way to increase as I go along?
playerDom = {1..playerDom.size+1};
players[playerDom.size] = new Player(name="Gretsky", position="Center", shoeSize=10, pid=playerDom.size);
writeln("I have %i players".format(playerDom.size));

playerDom = {1..playerDom.size+1};
players[playerDom.size] = new Player(name="Blake", position="Defenseman", shoeSize=12, pid=playerDom.size);
writeln("I have %i players".format(playerDom.size));

for p in players {
  writeln("Player %i has shoeSize %i".format(p.pid, p.shoeSize));
  p.shoeSize += 1;
}

for p in players {
  writeln("Player NOW %i has shoeSize %i".format(p.pid, p.shoeSize));
}

// poops during compilation
// domobj.chpl:31: error: the first argument of the 'by' operator is not a range
for p in players by -1 {
  writeln("Player NOW %i has shoeSize %i".format(p.pid, p.shoeSize));
}
```

Comment: Mind providing more details on `poops` here, e.g. what happened vs. what you expected? Compile-time failure? Execution-time failure? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: Also, if relevant, could you provide the declaration of `Players` and it's element-type? If not relevant, could we simplify this example to `Players` being an array of integers, where we update the value of each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range operation `by` does not work on arrays like you had hoped. Instead, we are left with the slightly less elegant form of iterating over the reversed indices as shown here:

```
for i in players.domain by -1 {
  writeln("Player NOW %i has shoeSize %i".format(players[i].pid, players[i].shoeSize));
}
```

Below is your larger code-block with some other cleanups:

```
var playerDom = {1..0},
    players: [playerDom] Player;

writeln("I have %i players".format(playerDom.size));
players.push_back(new Player(name="Gretsky", position="Center", shoeSize=10, pid=players.size+1));
writeln("I have %i players".format(playerDom.size));
players.push_back(new Player(name="Blake", position="Defenseman", shoeSize=12, pid=players.size+1));
writeln("I have %i players".format(playerDom.size));

for p in players {
  writeln("Player %i has shoeSize %i".format(p.pid, p.shoeSize));
  p.shoeSize += 1;
}

for p in players {
  writeln("Player NOW %i has shoeSize %i".format(p.pid, p.shoeSize));
}

for i in players.domain by -1 {
  ref p = players[i];
  writeln("Player NOW %i has shoeSize %i".format(p.pid, p.shoeSize));
}

class Player {
  var name: string,
      position: string,
      pid: int,
      shoeSize: int;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I wonder if `for element in array by -1 { ... }` *should* work in Chapel. This might be worth exploring as a feature request.